SCCM find who added device to specific collection
is there a way in SCCM to see who added a device to a specific collection ? I looked around but couldn't find a message Id with that information . i can who modified a collection but doesn't tell me what they did
any idea ?

If you only use the console, and no scripting you can definitely find the info in SMSProv.log but as so much stuff is logged there the information is lost very quickly, so I'm unsure if that is good enough for you. I am not 100% sure but I would not think it is stored elsewhere. (we use a custom tool to add devices via script and just log in that tool ourselves, which might also be a valid idea for the future if this feature is important for you)
